# Helm chart versions for CI/CD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm repository set up for my CI/CD pipeline, but the one thing I am having trouble with is helm's versioning system which is focused on a semantic versioning system as in `x.x.x`.

I want to be able to specify tags like "staging", "latest", and "production", and although I am able to successfully upload charts with string versions

`NAME               CHART VERSION   APP VERSION
chartmuseum/myrchart latest          1.0`

Any attempt to actually access the chart fails, such as

`helm inspect chartmuseum/mychart --version=latest`

Generates the error:

`Error: failed to download "chartmuseum/mychart" (hint: running 'helm repo update' may help)`

I don't really want to get into controlled semantic versioning at this point in development, or the mess that is appending hashes to a version. Is there any way to get helm to pull non-semantically tagged chart versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that worked for me. Since the semvar allows you to append values after the last number like `0.1.0-aebcaber`, I've taken to simply using `0.1.0-latest` and overwriting that in chartmuseum on uploads.

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this, where I do not want to version my chart (and subcharts) semanticaly as well is not to use helm repository at all and just pull whole chart in CI/CD from git instead. If you are publishing them to wider audience this may not suit you, but for own CI/CD which is authorized to access our repositories anyway it works like charm.

Comment: I found that I was able to simply tag things like `0.1.0-staging` it saves me some small trouble and separates concerns when doing update strategies

Comment: If you are just using a git repo to store your charts, how do you version your charts?

Comment: I store them in git, for this approach git == sha of commit == "version". This won't work for every situation as I stated originally, but there are cases when it's the easiest.